# Read JSON array from websocket data feed in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner in javascript and coding in general.
what i'm trying to do is to get the bid price (array) from this websocket data feed but i'm struggling,in my code i try to print(console.log) only the "bidPrice"and not everything else like "asksize","bidsize" etc etc
when i run my code i get only undefined and not the "bidPrice",
what is missing here? 
thank you for any help

**here the result (cmd) when i run the code not good!!!!**

```
C:\Users\Desktop\codesource>node wss.js
Connection opened
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

**here is my code in node.js:**

```
fs = require('fs');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime');
ws.on('open', function() {
    console.log('Connection opened');

    //out
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({"op": "subscribe", "args": ["quote:XBTUSD"]}));



});
//in            
ws.on('message',function(message){var response = JSON.parse(message) 

 fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', JSON.stringify(message));
 fs.writeFile('helloworld.json', JSON.stringify(message));


    var data = message;

    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(json["bidPrice"]);

});
```

**here is data coming from bitmex websocket**

```
Connection opened
{ info: 'Welcome to the BitMEX Realtime API.',enter code here
  version: '1.2.0',
  timestamp: '2016-12-28T22:27:15.000Z',
  docs: 'https://www.bitmex.com/app/wsAPI',
  heartbeatEnabled: false }
{ success: true,
  subscribe: 'quote:XBTUSD',
  request: { op: 'subscribe', args: [ 'quote:XBTUSD' ] } }
{ table: 'quote',
  keys: [],
  types:
   { timestamp: 'timestamp',
     symbol: 'symbol',
     bidSize: 'long',
     bidPrice: 'float',
     askPrice: 'float',
     askSize: 'long' },
  foreignKeys: { symbol: 'instrument' },
  attributes: { timestamp: 'sorted', symbol: 'grouped' },
  action: 'partial',
  data:
   [ { timestamp: '2016-12-28T22:26:54.645Z',
       symbol: 'XBTUSD',
       bidSize: 12,
       bidPrice: 969.59,
       askPrice: 971.06,
       askSize: 499 } ] }
```

it seems it doesn't work too

```
console.log(response.data[0].bidPrice);


Connection opened
C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codesource\wss.js:24
        console.log(response.data[0].bidPrice);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codesource\wss.js:24:27)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Receiver.ontext (C:\Users\jalal\Desktop\codesource\node_modules\ws\lib\WebSocket.js:841:10)
```

Comment: thanks but doesn't works maybe i'm missing somethings else

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
console.log(json["bidPrice"]);
```

to

```
console.log(response.data[0].bidPrice);
```

FYI you do not need the variables `data` and `json`

Comment: Are you sure he shouldn't be doing `response.data[o].bidPrice`?

Comment: console.log(response.data[0].bidPrice);
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @itriad if you `console.log(response)` what do you get?

Comment: @MattAltepeter { table: 'quote',
  action: 'insert',
  data:
   [ { timestamp: '2016-12-29T00:20:57.511Z',
       symbol: 'XBTUSD',
       bidSize: 2000,
       bidPrice: 972.66,
       askPrice: 974.07,
       askSize: 15000 } ] }

Comment: @itriad So I think `message` is already an object when you get it, meaning you do not need to use `JSON.parse()`. Try: `console.log(message.data[0].bidPrice)`

Comment: @MattAltepeter it does not work too,i'm really blocked !!!!!!   console.log(message.data[0].bidPrice)
                                           ^TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Hmm really thought that might do it. `console.log(typeof message)` for me?